# Content of a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a Cell in a TableView. The cell is connected to an Array, so it shows the hole list in the App. Now I want to make a switch statement based on which cell you click. Something like this:

```
switch Cell {

case "first":
variable = "1"

default:
variable = "0"

}
```

Til here everything works fine, even the switch statement works, but it is not based on the content of the Cell. The switch itself is working because on my SecondViewController I always get "0" to see. So what arguments do I have to put behind Cell in the switch statement, to get the content of Cell involved?

Comment: override a built in method called didSelectRowatIndexPath.
In general, override build in methods, google about table View delegate methods

Answer (score 2):

Implement the UITableViewDelegate function `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.  This will be called when you select a cell, and the index of the cell will be found in `indexPath.row`.  From there you can alter behavior based on which cell was selected.

Comment: Generally it's part of the view controller which is hosting the table view.  Personally, I like to make extensions (usually in the same file) to make it obvious where the delegate and data source functions are located.  That would be placed after the closing bracket of your view controller and look something like:
`extension MyViewController: UITableViewDelegate {`
`     // Implement delegate functions here`
`}`

You'll also need to make sure that your table view knows to use your view controller as its delegate.  If you're using a nib, right-click from the tableview to file's owner.